# Remove the default css styles tag in wp_head

Tags: html, css, wordpress, head

I would like to remove the default css styles tag in wp_head, such that:

BEFORE :

```
<head>
<link/>
<script/>
<style> 
...
...
...
</style>
</head>
```

AFTER :

```
<head>
<link/>
<script/>
</head>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Cleaned up the title since wordpress is one of the tags used on the question and made the question more concise and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Search the `wp_enqueue_style` method and show, which methods calling deeper.

`wp_enqueue_style` > `wp_styles` > `$wp_styles`

After you have tracked the methods, you see, you must handle the variable `$wp_styles`.

Create an `init`-Action in your Theme and override `$wp_styles`:

```
function removeStyles() {
    global $wp_styles;

    $wp_styles = null;
}
```

That's all. Another way ist, to get all registred style-names to deregister it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about inline css, you need to investigate through your theme and your different plugin.

Basically, any style is injected with the action [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

For example

```
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_function');
```

To remove these entries, if they are related to the style, you need to use [`remove_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'custom_function');
```

This way will work fine with procedural, if the action is thrown within a class

```
remove_action('wp_head', array('class_name', 'custom_function');
```

Don't forget to use the same priority for the `remove_action()` than the [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/), if need.
You can, also, remove an action, and add your own custom function with your own style definitions with a new add_action calling your function and move it where you want in the head when playing with the priority.